# How to access different types of classes in a single object array in C#

Tags: c#

I have an object array that is supposed to hold objects of different classes. I need to write down the attributes of those classes but don't know how to access them.

For example:

```
object[] NationalTeam;
```

possibly holding:

```
class Swimmer
class Runner
```

etc.

with different attributes. Can't access them with `NationalTeam[i]`. Can it be done with overloading [] indexer? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to either:

1. Cast them:

   ```
   object teamMember = NationalTeam[0];

   if (teamMember is Swimmer)
   {
       Swimmer swimmerTeamMember = (Swimmer)teamMember;
       // Work with swimmer
   }
   // ... and so on
   ```
2. Add and implement an interface or base class such as `ITeamMember` or `TeamMember`.

   ```
   interface ITeamMember { /* common properties */ }
   class Swimmer : ITeamMember { /* ... */ }
   ITeamMember[] NationalTeam;
   ```
3. Or use a combination of both.

Eric Lippert (one of the designers of C#) has a fantastic walk through to explain a very similar problem. I suggest that you read it. http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

Comment: Can't do 'object teamMember = NationalTeam[0];' becouse National team is still empty. It's not static.

Comment: I'm a newbe, need some clues.

Comment: @Thyl that's a separate question. You will have to narrow down how the data is stored

Comment: @Thyl i would ask that in a separate post.